# How to deal with images with an undefined height and width attribute for AMP pages?

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I am trying to create Google AMP versions of pages that contain a significant amount of user created html.

There are a lot of cases where there are img tags that do not have a height or width attribute set and the image source is a reference to an external URL.

I thought about making a request to the URL to get the image heights and widths and then setting the height and width attributes using those values but this doesn't seem like the right solution.

Another thing I tried was just setting the height and width to an arbitrary value and then trying to override the width and height attributes in the stylesheet by setting `amp-img {height:auto;width:auto}` but in that case the image will still rendered at the aspect ratio initially declared.

But back to my original question: How to deal with images with an undefined height and width attribute for AMP pages? What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

The most cases you have a special ratio for the Image. If you don't have the real size but the ratio you can declare like:

```
<amp-img src="image.jpg" width="16" height="9" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
or
<amp-img src="image.jpg" width="4" height="3" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
```

The width and height are only for calculate the space in the layout. And `layout="responsive"` fit the Image 100% in the top Layer. Usaly 100% width and height by the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
amp-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

The only issue is, if the image is smaller than the device's width, it will stretch the image and will cause some pixelation, however it keeps the same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION USING PHP

AMP requires inline amp-custom style sheet in each page header.

In the header of the main file, set `$imgsizeArr = getimagesize('serverLocationOfFile')`
$imgsizeArr[0] is the width in px.
$imgsizeArr[3] is the string, width="50" height="100", for html code.

The style sheet is a php file that is include_once after you get the image width.
In the style sheet file, echo the width of the image in the tag (id, class, or whatever) for the surrounding  tag. That is, the width must be defined in the  tag that surrounds the  tag.

E.g., in the main program,

```
if (file_exists('/myserver/myimg.jpg') {
  $imgsizeArr = getimagesize('/myserver/myimg.jpg');
  $thisimgwidth = $imgsizeArr[0];
  $thisimgstring = $imgsizeArr[3];

} else {
  //set it to something else
}

include_once 'amp_cust_style_sheet.php';
...
<div class="myamp_img">
  <amp-img src="/myimg.jpg" <? echo $thisimgstring; ?> layout="responsive" alt="" noloading="">
  </amp-img>
</div>
```

In the style sheet that is php and included in the header below where you get the variable $thisimgwidth,

```
<style amp-custom="">
...
.myamp_img { width : <? if (!empty($thisimgwidth) echo $thisimgwidth; else echo '0'; ?>px }
</style>
```

That should do it. You might be able to use something like this to to set a  static height by varying the widths of the wrapper  tag.

If you have a series of images, the classes can be added to the style sheet dynamically with php instead of trying to predict how many you'll have.

HTH!